# Why this function is freezing some pcs?

Tags: javascript

I have a function to know what exact time and days an employee works.

That function returns a value that is used in a datepicker. As said, I only want to display the "working hours," so I had to disable the "non-working" hours.

```js
var invalid_a = [
  "2021-03-17T13:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-03-17T13:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-03-17T13:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-03-17T13:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-03-17T13:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-03-17T13:00:00.000Z"
];

var invalid_b = [
  "2021-03-17T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-03-17T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-03-17T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-03-17T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-03-17T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-03-17T22:00:00.000Z"
];

var days_list = [
  "MO",
  "WE",
  "TH",
  "TU",
  "FR",
  "SA"
];

var comb = invalid_a.map(function combineTitleData(dataItem, index) {
  let y = new Date(dataItem);
  let mins = y.getMinutes() + 59;
  return {
    start: '00:00',
    end: '' + y.getHours() - 1 + ':' + '' + mins + '',
    recurring: { repeat: 'weekly', weekDays: days_list.toString() }
  };
});

var comb2 = invalid_b.map(function combineTitleData(dataItem, index) {
  return {
    start: '' + new Date(dataItem).getHours() + ':' + '01',
    end: '23:59',
    recurring: { repeat: 'weekly', weekDays: days_list.toString() }
  };
})    

console.log(comb);
console.log(comb2);
```

When I test this works well, some users (a couple of them) have reported that the browser freezes when this function is executed, a pop-up appears with: "Page Unresponsive" - You can wait for it to become responsive or exit the page.

I know this is the function causing this because when I disabled this code on the page and tried again, everything was working fine.

Why is this function causing this in some browsers/clients? Is there a different way to map the dates with my expected output that won't cause browser errors?

Thanks.

Comment: Your function is O(n) and I don't see anything wrong. Maybe the array is composed of millions of entries?

Comment: The only (micro) optimisation I can see is to compute `days_list.toString()` outside the loops since it never changes

Comment: @CristianTraìna the array contains only the data of the current user... isn't different from what's in that example

Comment: Where do the arrays come from? If the arrays were large enough you could conceivably stall the browser, but without additional info I don't see anything egregiously wrong with this. Is it possible that it's getting invoked repeatedly in a way you didn't intend?

Comment: @rayhatfield the arrays come from a database search, but it contains only the current user information, so the example is exactly the same that's running in the site.

Comment: Do the problem browsers / PCs have any particular browser extensions installed? Even some anti-virus programs can interfere with JS. What differentiates these particular environments? Have you tried using the browser auditing tools on these machines?

Answer (score 1):

Alike [@ArkyAsmal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16451347/arky-asmal) answer, I advise you to use web workers or, more easily, if your array is composed of millions of entries, just add a little timeout to flush the UI thread every ~10k iterations:

- Transform your `map` in a `for` loop
- Create an async context
- Use `await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 5))` if i%1E5===0

Comment: It's not the case, the arrays of the example is the exact scenario of the live site. The arrays are very small, as they contain only the current user data (working days, from one week)...

Comment: What does _"Create an async context"_ mean?

Comment: @Phil just create a function marked with the `async` keyword. This will provide an async context able to stop and resume the execution

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a performance issue. The time complexity is O(n), but if they contain thousands of data points, its a bad time.

Javascript is a single threaded language, so if there are a lot of employees/data points to compute, the browser will wait until completing this entire data analysis, before doing anything else (i.e any clicks on buttons, links, etc).

This can and will crash the UI if there are a lot of data points, making the page unresponsive.

This is actually a great candidate for asynchronous javascript programming.

Solutions:

1. Use web.worker api to use additional cpu threads to do this computation. By default, this makes these function asynchronous
2. Convert these functions to javascript promises, thereby allowing the UI to still respond, because the function calculations are offloaded.

Here is a good resource if you want to look into either: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: How exactly would you propose to convert these synchronous operation functions to promises?

Comment: But how this can be a performance issue with this small arrays? The real data that's passed is exactly the same of the example... I could understand if i'm passing thousand of entries on each array, but it's not the case

Comment: Ah interesting. @Ir0ngirll I noticed you said these are coming from a database right? Is fetching this data from the database asynchronous? If not, that will also cause crashes on clients that don't have the strongest internet connections.

Comment: No, it's not fetching the data @ArkyAsmal, the data is passed as plain text in the page loading as this is not sensitive data to speed up things. But good point about the "internet connections", these clients that had issues had bad internet connection at all.

Comment: @Ir0ngirll If you are trying to prevent crashes due to a slow internet connection issue, you can also fetch the text file on load, asynchronously (using promises). Aside from that, I don't see any further optimizations that can prevent this, if the data is small (i.e less than 30 data points), since your initial code is fine for that :) .